# Recording 24hrs of audio in multiple files

Tags: field-recording

I'm looking to record sound for a continuous 24hr period. I'd like the output to be in seamless chunks (of say 10mins) that I can work with easily. Is there any out-of-the box solution that would work?

Comment: Using what hardware? Mac can do it using [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) (assuming you have sufficient disk space) - idk of anything else that can.

Comment: Windows (or Linux)

Comment: Then I've no idea, sorry.

Comment: No problem, I'll keep searching. I think I have a plan!

Comment: Interested to know your plan. I use Audacity but chunking is manual.

Comment: @steveOw I was thinking of doing that, but Audacity's manual didn't leave me confident that it would do the whole recording (it says something like there's not real limit to the length of time other than RAM and some non-specific things). And I didn't know if it would be able to handle the file if it did make it. In the end, I decided a 200ms break every 30mins wasn't too much of a big deal, and went with recording using SoX.

Comment: I have not used SoX but it looks interesting. Can you achieve the standard-length-multiple-output-file recording with a single SoX command?

Comment: @steveOw Not a single command, just wrote a batch script, it was about 5 lines long.

Comment: Any chance you could share it?

Comment: @steveOw yeah I can, it's on another machine which I won't have access to until tomorrow, I'll try to remember though!

Comment: @lucas Not to worry - I see that there is an example .bat file in the downloaded sox directory, I'll try and work out how you did the looping myself.

Comment: If anyone's interested, the following single-line sox command (issued at the windows command prompt) will record a series of single-channel, 30 second long WAV files until you do a ctrl+break:... rec -c1 "localsubdir1/fred_.wav" trim 0 0:30 : newfile : restart. Filenames will increment fred_001, fred_002, ... etc.